# Error when updating sbt using apt [Ubuntu]

Tags: sbt, installation, apt

> Setting up sbt (0.13.15.3) ... /usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash:
> line 73: java: command not found
>
> dpkg: error processing package sbt
> (--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned
> error exit status 127

I have the Java bin directory in PATH and I've also set JAVA_HOME:

> $ java -version
>
> openjdk version "1.8.0_131" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b11)
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)